# convert cosine similarity distance to confidence percent

Tags: python, numpy, cosine-similarity

I am working to features of images based on deep learning techniques, and for labeling images, I specify the desired label with a threshold using cosine distance.
The algorithm is as follows:

```
import math
from itertools import izip

def dot_product(v1, v2):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], izip(v1, v2)))

def cosine_measure(v1, v2):
    prod = dot_product(v1, v2)
    len1 = math.sqrt(dot_product(v1, v1))
    len2 = math.sqrt(dot_product(v2, v2))
    return prod / (len1 * len2)
```

Suppose I get the number 0.34. How do I convert this number to a percentage?

Comment: how would a cosine similarity map onto percentages? why would you want to do such a thing? percentages of what?

Comment: yes,Using cosine similarity, I get the similarity of one image to another, and I have to show these numbers as a percentage in the output for better representation and meaning.
The cosine sim threshold value for the similarity of an object is 0.4. That is, when this number is greater than 0.4, this object is the same, otherwise it is not the same. But I need to get these numbers. As a percentage of similarity achieved

Answer (score 0):

Cosine is a sinosoidal function which is a non-linear function. Thus calculating linear distances from cosine values would be a mistake. One good approximation would be treating cosine angle as linearly spaced and finding distance from cosine inverse function i.e. angle instead of cosine value itself.

```
 import math
 cos_sim = cosine_measure(v1, v2)
 perc_dist = (math.pi - math.acos(cos_sim)) * 100 / math.pi
```